# Syncing custom fields between QuoteLineItem and OpportunityLineItem

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity-lineitem, quotelineitem

I'm trying to syncronize between two custom fields on `QuoteLineItem` and `OpportunityLineItem` named `Field1__c` and `Field2__c`.

So after inserting the `QuoteLineItem` the two fields will be updated on the `OpportunityLineItem`.

I created a formula field on `QuoteLineItem` to get the `OpportunityLineItem` `ID` after insert in order to user in my class.

The problem is, I can see clearly the `OpportunityLineItem`  `ID` on my presentation page. but the code doesnt bring it at all. I'm using a JSON for that matter.

any idea why?

**METHOD:**

```
public static void syncronizeQLI(list <QuoteLineItem> lstQLI){

map<string,string> mapQuoteOppty=new map<string,string>();
string JSONContent=Json.Serialize(lstQLI);
System.debug('##### JSONCONTENT      '+JSONContent);
JSONParser parser =JSON.createParser(JSONContent);
list<string> OpptyLineId=new list<string>();
list<string> QuoteLineId=new list<string>();

System.debug('parser-------->'+parser );

while (parser.nextToken() != null) 
{
    if(parser.getCurrentToken()==JSONToken.VALUE_STRING && parser.getCurrentName()=='OpportunityLineItemId__c')
    OpptyLineId.add(parser.getText());

    if(parser.getCurrentToken()==JSONToken.VALUE_STRING && parser.getCurrentName()=='Id')
    QuoteLineId.add(parser.getText());

    parser.nextToken();

    if(parser.getCurrentToken()==JSONToken.VALUE_STRING && parser.getCurrentName()=='OpportunityLineItemId__c')
    OpptyLineId.add(parser.getText());

    if(parser.getCurrentToken()==JSONToken.VALUE_STRING && parser.getCurrentName()=='Id')
    QuoteLineId.add(parser.getText());
}

System.debug('OpptyLineId-------->'+OpptyLineId);
System.debug('QuoteLineId-------->'+QuoteLineId);

integer iCount=0;
for(string strOppLineId : OpptyLineId)
{
    string iQuoteLineId=QuoteLineId[iCount];
    mapQuoteOppty.put(iQuoteLineId,strOppLineId);
    iCount++;
}
System.debug('************ MAP QUOTE OPP            '+mapQuoteOppty);
Set<Id> SetOppId=new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> SetQuoteId=new Set<Id>();
for(QuoteLineItem QLI : lstQLI)
{
    SetQuoteId.add(QLI.QuoteId);
}
List<Quote> Lstquotes =[SELECT id, OpportunityId, isSyncing FROM Quote WHERE isSyncing = true AND Id in :SetQuoteId];
for(Quote Qt:Lstquotes)
{
    SetOppId.add(Qt.OpportunityId);
}

List<OpportunityLineItem> lstOLI=[select Id, OpportunityId,Field1__c,Field2__c from OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId in:SetOppId];

Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem> MapOLI=new Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem>([select Id,OpportunityId, Field2__c, Field1__c  from OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId in:SetOppId]);

Map<Id,QuoteLineItem > MapQLI=new map<Id,QuoteLineItem>([Select Id,QuoteId, Field2__c, Field1__c from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId in:SetQuoteId]);

list<OpportunityLineItem> updateQuoteLineItem =new list<OpportunityLineItem >();


for(QuoteLineItem qli:MapQLI.values())
{
system.debug(' -------- QLI.ID         '+qli.id);
system.debug('mapQuoteOppty.get(qli.id) '+mapQuoteOppty.get(qli.id));
       if(mapQuoteOppty.get(qli.id)!=null)
   {
      String OppID = mapQuoteOppty.get(qli.id);
      System.debug('###### OPPID      -----------  '+OppID);
      OpportunityLineItem OLI = MapOLI.get(OppID);
      qli.Field1__c=OLI.Field2__c;
      qli.Field2__c=OLI.Field1__c;   

      updateQuoteLineItem.add(OLI);
   }

}
system.debug('UPDATES QUOTE LINE ITEM LIST        '+updateQuoteLineItem);
update updateQuoteLineItem;
}
```

**TRIGGER:**

```
trigger QuoteLineItemAfterInsert on QuoteLineItem (before insert, after insert){
list<QuoteLineItem> lstQLI = new list <QuoteLineItem>();
for ( QuoteLineItem qli : trigger.new){
    lstQLI.add(qli);
}
system.debug('LIST QLI TRIGGER           '+ lstQLI);
if(lstQLI.size()>0){
    AP001_SyncronazingQLI_OLI.syncronizeQLI(lstQLI);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like "OpportunityLineItemId" field on Quote Line Item object is a special field.

```
SELECT Id, OpportunityLineItemId FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE QuoteId ='0Q01N00000xxxxxxx' AND OpportunityLineItemId != null
```

If I remove "OpportunityLineItemId" from WHERE clause, it does show me the the id. But adding the condition does not show any records. Tried it in trigger and developer console, same result.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Custom Quote Sync](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Iop5EAC)? At least install it into a sandbox and take a look at the code & see how it works.

But with your own code, why are you using JSON? Just use the native sObjects, so this:

```
while (parser.nextToken() != null) 
{
    if(parser.getCurrentToken()==JSONToken.VALUE_STRING && parser.getCurrentName()=='OpportunityLineItemId__c')
    OpptyLineId.add(parser.getText());

    if(parser.getCurrentToken()==JSONToken.VALUE_STRING && parser.getCurrentName()=='Id')
    QuoteLineId.add(parser.getText());

    parser.nextToken();

    if(parser.getCurrentToken()==JSONToken.VALUE_STRING && parser.getCurrentName()=='OpportunityLineItemId__c')
    OpptyLineId.add(parser.getText());

    if(parser.getCurrentToken()==JSONToken.VALUE_STRING && parser.getCurrentName()=='Id')
    QuoteLineId.add(parser.getText());
}
```

becomes this:

```
for (QuoteLineItem qli : lstQLI) {

    OpptyLineId.add(qli.OpportunityLineItemId__c);
    QuoteLineId.add(qli.Id);
}
```

Also, you might benefit from reading [Trigger Frameworks and Apex Trigger Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)

Comment: Yes you're right but still have OpptyLineId NULL :/

Comment: OK, print the content of lstQLI at the start of syncronizeQLI().

Comment: I did already and I had OpportunityLineItemId__c=null even the trigger is after insert but I got OpportunityLineItemId__c data on the record

Comment: Is the Quote synced with the Opportunity?

Comment: Yes its synced, and I'm querying again the quote to sync the custom field only with synced quote

Comment: 'formula field on QuoteLineItem' can you post this formula field please?

Comment: The formula contain: OpportunityLineItem.Id

Comment: Davin, the QLI sync problem is extremely complex, and it would be more valuable to see actual working code or advice on the specific problem at hand.